# How to authenticated Google Cloud Endpoint call from an iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth

My google backend APIs are using `Oauth` 2.0, when i call one of my api with that code :

```
func userService() -> GTLServiceUserController{
    var service : GTLServiceUserController? = nil
    if service == nil {
        service = GTLServiceUserController()
        service?.retryEnabled = true
    }
    return service!
}
```

And

```
func callApi() {
    let service = userService()
    let query = GTLQueryUserController.queryForGetAllUsers()
    service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket!, object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            print("Error :\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        let resp = object as? GTLUserControllerOperationResponse
        if(resp != nil){
            print(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting  `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException: unauthorized)`

I already read this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Adding_a_sign-in_dialog_to_your_iOS_client), but i don't want my users to log in, instead i want my app to present its credentials to the service for authentication without user interaction.

I want to use this [approach](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but they are not telling how to do it with iOS apps.

So basically i want to be able to call my APIs successfully without any user interaction or sign-in dialog.

Please note that i have those classes on my project :

- GTMOAuth2Authentication
- GTMOAuth2SignIn
- GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to authenticate individual users (via OAuth2 login), then you do not need to do anything else and your App can directly call the API (as described in the "Calling the Endpoint API (unauthenticated)" section).

Service accounts are for server-to-server interactions and cannot be used to authenticate individual users; if you embed a service account & key within your iOS App, anyone can extract it from the App and start calling your API, hence it does not add any security.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, can you tell me how i can embed my service account & key into my app please ?

Comment: How i can use google default credentials ? and is there an iOS version of GoogleAuthUtil library like android ?